# How to output CDATA from within an xsl:function call?

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

In my XSLT I'm trying to create elements inside a foreach and with the help of a function.

```
        <xsl:variable name="artistList" as="xs:string*"><xsl:apply-templates select="@artist"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="$artistList">
            <xsl:comment select="."></xsl:comment>
            <xsl:copy-of select="cst:createArtistEntity('artist', ., 'Artist_')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
```

And the function itself as follows;

```
<xsl:function name="cst:createArtistEntity">
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:param name="artistPrefix" />
    <ChunkEntity>
        <EntityType>Artist</EntityType>
        <EntityReference><xsl:value-of select="cst-ext:digest(concat($artistPrefix, $value))" /></EntityReference>
        <Column>
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></Name>
            <Value>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
            </Value>
        </Column>
    </ChunkEntity>
</xsl:function>
```

The output should be like:

```
   <ChunkEntity>
      <EntityType>Artist</EntityType>
      <EntityReference>b325f9fd1f0642c310c0168e061805f8</EntityReference>
      <Column>
         <Name>artist</Name>
         <Value><![CDATA[Jon Bon Jovi]]></Value>
      </Column>
   </ChunkEntity>
```

However inside my foreach and with the use the function call, the angle brackets of the CDATA are kept as `&gt;` etc. When I copy the code inside the function straight into the loop, it all works. Setting `disable-output-escaping` to 'no' doesn't do anything.

So the problem is pinpointed to the fact that I'm using a function or a copy-of, but I'm confused. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two changes:

1. In your function, set `disable-output-escaping` to `yes`:

   ```
   <Value>
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
   </Value>
   ```
2. When calling your function, use `xsl:sequence` rather than
   `xsl:copy-of`:

   ```
   <xsl:sequence select="cst:createArtistEntity('artist', ., 'Artist_')" />
   ```

   **Explanation:** In the course of copying, `xsl:copy-of` re-escapes `<` and `>` whereas `xsl:sequence` references the original nodes without copying (or escaping).

Comment: The DOE 'no' was left over from debugging. But the 'sequence' actually works. Thank you so much! Would you mind explaining what is happening here?

Comment: DOE: understood.  Sequence: good question: it references original rather than copying; answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the contents of a `Value` element to be serialized as a CDATA section then you should use `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="Value"/>`.

Comment: Ooh.. that's also a really good idea. I didn't know that existed! Thanks